# SubQuery added to existing Query in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am sure this is simple to do and I am missing something on formatting but I want to add the following query:

```
SELECT s.stud_id,
  jb.REGION,
  jt.DISTRICT
FROM pa_student s,
  (SELECT su.stud_id,
    rf.user_desc REGION
  FROM pa_stud_user su,
    pa_usrrf_stud rf
  WHERE su.col_num  = rf.col_num
  AND su.user_value = rf.user_id
  AND su.col_num    = 300) JB,
  (SELECT su.stud_id,
    rf.user_desc DISTRICT
  FROM pa_stud_user su,
    pa_usrrf_stud rf
  WHERE su.col_num  = rf.col_num
  AND su.user_value = rf.user_id
  AND su.col_num    = 400) JT
WHERE s.stud_id = jb.stud_id (+)
AND s.stud_id   = jt.stud_id (+)
```

To the existing query (both of these work fine by themselves)

```
SELECT sqc.CPNT_TYP_ID AS cpntTypeID ,
  sqc.CPNT_ID          AS cpntID ,
  sqc.REV_DTE          AS revDate,
  sqc.COMPL_DTE        AS complDate,
  sqc.CMPL_STAT_ID     AS cmplStatID,
  sqc.REQ_DTE          AS reqDate,
  cpt.CPNT_TITLE       AS cpntTtile,
  cpt.RTYP_ID ,
  cpt.DMN_ID ,
  cpt.DEL_MTH_ID ,
  cpt.CPNT_SRC_ID ,
  cpt.NOTACTIVE ,
  cpt.SAFETY_REL ,
  cpt.CREATE_DTE,
  cpt.REV_NUM AS cpntRevNum,
  cpt.REVISER ,
  cpt.APPRVR ,
  cpt.APPRVD ,
  cpt.APPRVL_DTE ,
  cpt.MIN_ENRL ,
  cpt.MAX_ENRL ,
  cpt.CPNT_LEN ,
  cpt.PREP_LEN ,
  cpt.LES_PLAN ,
  cpt.CONTACT ,
  cpt.CREDIT_HRS,
  cpt.CPE_HRS ,
  cpt.CONTACT_HRS ,
  cpt.STUD_MATS ,
  cpt.INST_MATS ,
  cpt.CPNT_DESC ,
  cpt.TGT_AUDNC ,
  cpt.COMMENTS ,
  cpt.GRADE_OPT ,
  cpt.ENRL_THRESHOLD_DAYS ,
  cpt.SHIPPING_REQUIRED,
  cpt.AUTO_FILL_ENRL ,
  cpt.WAITLIST_REMDR_SENT,
  cpt.AUTO_COMPETENCY ,
  cpt.CPNT_CLASSIFICATION ,
  cpt.CHGBCK_METHOD ,
  cpt.CATALOG_SKU ,
  cpt.SCHEDULE_CAN_OVERRIDE_PRICE ,
  cpt.PRODUCTION_READY,
  cpt.CPNT_GOALS ,
  cpt.SELF_RECORD_LRNGEVT ,
  cpt.SUB_RECORD_LRNGEVT ,
  cpt.TAP_DEF_ID ,
  cpt.APPROVAL_REQD ,
  cpt.INIT_PERIOD_TYPE_ID ,
  cpt.INIT_NUMBER ,
  cpt.INIT_BASIS_TYPE_ID,
  cpt.RETRNG_PERIOD_TYPE_ID ,
  cpt.RETRNG_NUMBER ,
  cpt.RETRNG_BASIS_TYPE_ID ,
  cpt.RATING ,
  cpt.SELF_ENRL ,
  cpt.USER_REQ_ENABLED ,
  cpt.USER_CAN_WAITLIST ,
  cpt.CPNT_KEY,
  cpt.REGISTER_ONLINE ,
  cpt.ESIG_ENABLED ,
  cs.CMPL_STAT_DESC AS cmplStatDesc,
  s.stud_id,
  s.fname,
  s.lname,
  s.mi,
  s.STUD_ID AS studID,
  s.LNAME   AS lastName,
  s.FNAME   AS firstName,
  s.MI      AS middleName,
  s.EMP_STAT_ID ,
  s.EMP_TYP_ID,
  s.JL_ID ,
  s.JP_ID ,
  s.TARGET_JP_ID ,
  s.JOB_TITLE ,
  s.DMN_ID ,
  s.ORG_ID,
  s.REGION_ID,
  s.CO_ID ,
  DECODE(s.NOTACTIVE, 'Y','N','N','Y') AS studActive ,
  s.ADDR ,
  s.CITY ,
  s.STATE ,
  s.POSTAL ,
  s.CNTRY ,
  s.SUPER ,
  s.COACH_STUD_ID ,
  s.HIRE_DTE,
  s.TERM_DTE ,
  s.EMAIL_ADDR,
  s.RESUME_LOCN ,
  s.COMMENTS ,
  s.SHIPPING_NAME ,
  s.SHIPPING_CONTACT_NAME,
  s.SHIPPING_ADDR ,
  s.SHIPPING_ADDR1 ,
  s.SHIPPING_CITY ,
  s.SHIPPING_STATE,
  s.SHIPPING_POSTAL ,
  s.SHIPPING_CNTRY ,
  s.SHIPPING_PHON_NUM ,
  s.SHIPPING_FAX_NUM ,
  s.SHIPPING_EMAIL_ADDR ,
  s.STUD_PSWD ,
  s.PIN ,
  s.PIN_DATE,
  s.ENCRYPTED ,
  s.HAS_ACCESS ,
  s.BILLING_NAME ,
  s.BILLING_CONTACT_NAME ,
  s.BILLING_ADDR ,
  s.BILLING_ADDR1 ,
  s.BILLING_CITY ,
  s.BILLING_STATE ,
  s.BILLING_POSTAL,
  s.BILLING_CNTRY ,
  s.BILLING_PHON_NUM ,
  s.BILLING_FAX_NUM ,
  s.BILLING_EMAIL_ADDR ,
  s.SELF_REGISTRATION ,
  s.SELF_REGISTRATION_DATE,
  s.ACCESS_TO_ORG_FIN_ACT ,
  s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_ADD ,
  s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_MOD ,
  s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_REMOVE ,
  s.NOTIFY_WHEN_SUB_ITEM_COMPLETE ,
  s.NOTIFY_WHEN_SUB_ITEM_FAILURE ,
  s.LOCKED ,
  s.PASSWORD_EXP_DATE,
  s.SECURITY_QUESTION ,
  s.SECURITY_ANSWER ,
  s.ROLE_ID ,
  s.IMAGE_ID ,
  s.GENDER ,
  s.PAST_SERVICE,
  s.LST_UNLOCK_TSTMP,
  s.MANAGE_SUB_SP,
  s.MANAGE_OWN_SP,
  NVL(userPref.preferred_timezone,pkg_state.get_default_timezone)            AS preferred_timezone,
  sq.qual_id                                                                 AS qualID,
  sq.assgn_dte                                                               AS assignDate,
  sq.qual_id_root                                                            AS qualIDRoot,
  q.qual_title                                                               AS qualTitle,
  q.DMN_ID                                                                   AS qualDomain,
  q.QUAL_TYP_ID                                                              AS qualTypeID ,
  q.NOTACTIVE                                                                AS qualNotActive ,
  q.CREATE_DTE                                                               AS qualCreateDate,
  q.QUAL_DESC                                                                AS qualDesc,
  q.FORCE_INCOMPLETE                                                         AS qualForceIncomplete,
  q.BASIS_DATE                                                               AS qualBasisDate,
  q.ESIG_ENABLED                                                             AS qualEsigEnabled,
  pkg_student.get_stud_qual_status (sq.stud_id, sq.qual_id, sq.qual_id_root) AS complete
FROM PA_STUD_QUAL_CPNT sqc,
  PA_CPNT cpt,
  PA_CMPL_STAT cs,
  pa_student s,
  pa_user_preference userPref,
  pa_qual q,
  (SELECT sq.stud_id,
    sq.qual_id,
    sq.assgn_dte,
    sq.qual_id_root,
    row_number() over (partition BY sq.stud_id,sq.qual_id order by sq.assgn_dte) rnum
  FROM
    (SELECT sq.stud_id,
      sq.qual_id,
      sq.assgn_dte,
      sq.qual_id_root
    FROM pa_stud_qual_relation sq,
      ( SELECT sq.stud_id FROM pa_stud_qual sq WHERE 1=1
      /** and sq.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
      /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
      UNION
      SELECT sq.stud_id
      FROM pa_stud_qual_relation sq
      WHERE 1=1
        /** and sq.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
        /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
      ) students
    WHERE sq.stud_id = students.stud_id
    /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch]*/
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sq.stud_id,
      sq.qual_id,
      sq.assgn_dte,
      sq.qual_id_root
    FROM pa_stud_qual_relation sq,
      pa_qual_relation qr,
      ( SELECT sq.stud_id FROM pa_stud_qual sq WHERE 1=1
      /** and sq.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
      /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
      UNION
      SELECT sq.stud_id
      FROM pa_stud_qual_relation sq
      WHERE 1=1
        /** and sq.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
        /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
      ) students
    WHERE sq.stud_id     = students.stud_id
    AND qr.qual_id_child = sq.qual_id
      /** and qr.qual_id_parent in [CurriculumSearch]*/
    ) sq
  ) sq
WHERE sqc.STUD_ID (+)     = sq.stud_id
AND sqc.QUAL_ID (+)       = sq.qual_id
AND sqc.QUAL_ID_ROOT(+)   = sq.qual_id_root
AND sqc.CPNT_TYP_ID       = cpt.CPNT_TYP_ID (+)
AND sqc.CPNT_ID           = cpt.CPNT_ID (+)
AND sqc.REV_DTE           = cpt.REV_DTE (+)
AND sqc.CMPL_STAT_ID      = cs.CMPL_STAT_ID (+)
AND s.stud_id             = sq.stud_id
AND s.stud_id             = userPref.user_id(+)
AND userPref.user_type(+) = 'S'
AND sq.rnum               = 1
AND sq.qual_id            = q.qual_id
  /** and [security:pa_student s]*/
```

I have tried so many different formats that I am confused beyond my knowledge of SQL... any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear God. Someone please codify this.

Comment: @Sathya: I answered your prayer. Not sure it helps much. :-)

Comment: @Joe Thank you! Anything better than the original state!

Comment: it's not really clear what your problem is....

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to add the first query to the second.

Comment: So another words I want to add Query 1 to Query 2 but can not get past the syntax errors.

Comment: The problem is I do not know at what location in Query 2 to add the subquery 1 and generate the output I need.

Comment: Why did you tag it with "psql"? psql is the commandline shell for PostgreSQL, but you are using the DECODE() function which is an Oracle thing...

Comment: What's the significance of col_num = 300 & 400 ? I can't make out what the query does.

Comment: 300 and 400 select a specific District and Region from the files referenced.

Comment: I am referencing an Oracle DB and using Oracle SQL Developer to test the launch the Query.  The end result will be a report in the BIRT tool that extracts data from an Oracle DB.

Comment: Getting this error when both Queries are combined:Error at Command Line:157 Column:13
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

I combined it. It took great pain. Please try this query and good luck:

```
SELECT sqc.CPNT_TYP_ID AS cpntTypeID,
    sqc.CPNT_ID        AS cpntID,
    sqc.REV_DTE        AS revDate,
    sqc.COMPL_DTE      AS complDate,
    sqc.CMPL_STAT_ID   AS cmplStatID,
    sqc.REQ_DTE        AS reqDate,
    cpt.CPNT_TITLE     AS cpntTtile,
    cpt.RTYP_ID,
    cpt.DMN_ID,
    cpt.DEL_MTH_ID,
    cpt.CPNT_SRC_ID,
    cpt.NOTACTIVE,
    cpt.SAFETY_REL,
    cpt.CREATE_DTE,
    cpt.REV_NUM AS cpntRevNum,
    cpt.REVISER,
    cpt.APPRVR,
    cpt.APPRVD,
    cpt.APPRVL_DTE,
    cpt.MIN_ENRL,
    cpt.MAX_ENRL,
    cpt.CPNT_LEN,
    cpt.PREP_LEN,
    cpt.LES_PLAN,
    cpt.CONTACT,
    cpt.CREDIT_HRS,
    cpt.CPE_HRS,
    cpt.CONTACT_HRS,
    cpt.STUD_MATS,
    cpt.INST_MATS,
    cpt.CPNT_DESC,
    cpt.TGT_AUDNC,
    cpt.COMMENTS,
    cpt.GRADE_OPT,
    cpt.ENRL_THRESHOLD_DAYS,
    cpt.SHIPPING_REQUIRED,
    cpt.AUTO_FILL_ENRL,
    cpt.WAITLIST_REMDR_SENT,
    cpt.AUTO_COMPETENCY,
    cpt.CPNT_CLASSIFICATION,
    cpt.CHGBCK_METHOD,
    cpt.CATALOG_SKU,
    cpt.SCHEDULE_CAN_OVERRIDE_PRICE,
    cpt.PRODUCTION_READY,
    cpt.CPNT_GOALS,
    cpt.SELF_RECORD_LRNGEVT,
    cpt.SUB_RECORD_LRNGEVT,
    cpt.TAP_DEF_ID,
    cpt.APPROVAL_REQD,
    cpt.INIT_PERIOD_TYPE_ID,
    cpt.INIT_NUMBER,
    cpt.INIT_BASIS_TYPE_ID,
    cpt.RETRNG_PERIOD_TYPE_ID,
    cpt.RETRNG_NUMBER,
    cpt.RETRNG_BASIS_TYPE_ID,
    cpt.RATING,
    cpt.SELF_ENRL,
    cpt.USER_REQ_ENABLED,
    cpt.USER_CAN_WAITLIST,
    cpt.CPNT_KEY,
    cpt.REGISTER_ONLINE,
    cpt.ESIG_ENABLED,
    cs.CMPL_STAT_DESC AS cmplStatDesc,
    s.stud_id,
    s.fname,
    s.lname,
    s.mi,
    s.STUD_ID AS studID,
    s.LNAME   AS lastName,
    s.FNAME   AS firstName,
    s.MI      AS middleName,
    s.EMP_STAT_ID,
    s.EMP_TYP_ID,
    s.JL_ID,
    s.JP_ID,
    s.TARGET_JP_ID,
    s.JOB_TITLE,
    s.DMN_ID,
    s.ORG_ID,
    s.REGION_ID,
    s.CO_ID,
    DECODE(s.NOTACTIVE, 'Y','N','N','Y') AS studActive,
    s.ADDR,
    s.CITY,
    s.STATE,
    s.POSTAL,
    s.CNTRY,
    s.SUPER,
    s.COACH_STUD_ID,
    s.HIRE_DTE,
    s.TERM_DTE,
    s.EMAIL_ADDR,
    s.RESUME_LOCN,
    s.COMMENTS,
    s.SHIPPING_NAME,
    s.SHIPPING_CONTACT_NAME,
    s.SHIPPING_ADDR,
    s.SHIPPING_ADDR1,
    s.SHIPPING_CITY,
    s.SHIPPING_STATE,
    s.SHIPPING_POSTAL,
    s.SHIPPING_CNTRY,
    s.SHIPPING_PHON_NUM,
    s.SHIPPING_FAX_NUM,
    s.SHIPPING_EMAIL_ADDR,
    s.STUD_PSWD,
    s.PIN,
    s.PIN_DATE,
    s.ENCRYPTED,
    s.HAS_ACCESS,
    s.BILLING_NAME,
    s.BILLING_CONTACT_NAME,
    s.BILLING_ADDR,
    s.BILLING_ADDR1,
    s.BILLING_CITY,
    s.BILLING_STATE,
    s.BILLING_POSTAL,
    s.BILLING_CNTRY,
    s.BILLING_PHON_NUM,
    s.BILLING_FAX_NUM,
    s.BILLING_EMAIL_ADDR,
    s.SELF_REGISTRATION,
    s.SELF_REGISTRATION_DATE,
    s.ACCESS_TO_ORG_FIN_ACT,
    s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_ADD,
    s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_MOD,
    s.NOTIFY_DEV_PLAN_ITEM_REMOVE,
    s.NOTIFY_WHEN_SUB_ITEM_COMPLETE,
    s.NOTIFY_WHEN_SUB_ITEM_FAILURE,
    s.LOCKED,
    s.PASSWORD_EXP_DATE,
    s.SECURITY_QUESTION,
    s.SECURITY_ANSWER,
    s.ROLE_ID,
    s.IMAGE_ID,
    s.GENDER,
    s.PAST_SERVICE,
    s.LST_UNLOCK_TSTMP,
    s.MANAGE_SUB_SP,
    s.MANAGE_OWN_SP,
    NVL(userPref.preferred_timezone,pkg_state.get_default_timezone)            AS preferred_timezone,
    sq.qual_id                                                                 AS qualID,
    sq.assgn_dte                                                               AS assignDate,
    sq.qual_id_root                                                            AS qualIDRoot,
    q.qual_title                                                               AS qualTitle,
    q.DMN_ID                                                                   AS qualDomain,
    q.QUAL_TYP_ID                                                              AS qualTypeID,
    q.NOTACTIVE                                                                AS qualNotActive,
    q.CREATE_DTE                                                               AS qualCreateDate,
    q.QUAL_DESC                                                                AS qualDesc,
    q.FORCE_INCOMPLETE                                                         AS qualForceIncomplete,
    q.BASIS_DATE                                                               AS qualBasisDate,
    q.ESIG_ENABLED                                                             AS qualEsigEnabled,
    pkg_student.get_stud_qual_status (sq.stud_id, sq.qual_id, sq.qual_id_root) AS complete,
    /**-- Added from smaller query */
    jb.REGION,
    jt.DISTRICT
    /**-- Added from smaller query */
FROM PA_STUD_QUAL_CPNT sqc,
PA_CPNT cpt,
PA_CMPL_STAT cs,
pa_student s,
pa_user_preference userPref,
pa_qual q,
(
    SELECT sq.stud_id, sq.qual_id, sq.assgn_dte, sq.qual_id_root, row_number() over (partition BY sq.stud_id,sq.qual_id order by sq.assgn_dte) rnum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT sq.stud_id, sq.qual_id, sq.assgn_dte, sq.qual_id_root
        FROM pa_stud_qual_relation sq,
        (
            SELECT sq.stud_id FROM pa_stud_qual sq WHERE 1=1
            /** and sq.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
            /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
            UNION
            SELECT sq.stud_id FROM pa_stud_qual_relation sq WHERE 1=1
            /** and sq.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
            /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
        ) students
        WHERE sq.stud_id = students.stud_id
        /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch]*/
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sq.stud_id, sq.qual_id, sq.assgn_dte, sq.qual_id_root
        FROM pa_stud_qual_relation sq,
        pa_qual_relation qr,
        (
            SELECT sq.stud_id FROM pa_stud_qual sq WHERE 1=1
            /** and sq.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
            /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
            UNION
            SELECT sq.stud_id FROM pa_stud_qual_relation sq WHERE 1=1
            /** and sq.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
            /** and sq.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
        ) students
        WHERE sq.stud_id = students.stud_id
            AND qr.qual_id_child = sq.qual_id
        /** and qr.qual_id_parent in [CurriculumSearch]*/
    ) sq
) sq,
/**-- Added from smaller query */
(
    SELECT su.stud_id, rf.user_desc as REGION
    FROM pa_stud_user su
    JOIN pa_usrrf_stud rf on rf.col_num = su.col_num
    WHERE su.user_value = rf.user_id
        AND su.col_num = 300
) JB,
(
    SELECT su.stud_id, rf.user_desc as DISTRICT
    FROM pa_stud_user su
    JOIN pa_usrrf_stud rf on rf.col_num = su.col_num
    WHERE su.user_value = rf.user_id
        AND su.col_num = 400
) JT
/**-- Added from smaller query */
WHERE sqc.STUD_ID             = sq.stud_id
    AND sqc.QUAL_ID           = sq.qual_id
    AND sqc.QUAL_ID_ROOT      = sq.qual_id_root
    AND sqc.CPNT_TYP_ID       = cpt.CPNT_TYP_ID
    AND sqc.CPNT_ID           = cpt.CPNT_ID
    AND sqc.REV_DTE           = cpt.REV_DTE
    AND sqc.CMPL_STAT_ID      = cs.CMPL_STAT_ID
    AND s.stud_id             = sq.stud_id
    AND s.stud_id             = userPref.user_id
    AND userPref.user_type    = 'S'
    AND sq.rnum               = 1
    AND sq.qual_id            = q.qual_id
    /**-- Added from smaller query */
    AND s.stud_id             = jb.stud_id
    AND s.stud_id             = jt.stud_id
    /**-- Added from smaller query */
    /** and [security:pa_student s]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler than you think.

**Option One (recommended)**
Turn the simplified first query into a function (probably embedded in another package)

```
FUNCTION get_user_desc(p_stud_id NUMBER,p_col_num NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  FOR q_rec IN (SELECT rf.user_desc user_desc
                FROM pa_stud_user su,
                     pa_usrrf_stud rf
                WHERE su.col_num  = rf.col_num
                AND su.user_value = rf.user_id
                AND su.col_num    = p_col_num
                AND su.stud_id    = p_stud_id
               ) LOOP
    RETURN q_rec.user_desc;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
```

And Then add the two columns to the "Original Query"

```
get_user_desc(sq.stud_id,300) AS region,
get_user_desc(sq.stud_id,400) AS district
```

**Option 2 if you don't want to create the function above**

Add two new queries as new columns in the second query.

```
SELECT
...  ...
( SELECT rf.user_desc as region
  FROM pa_stud_user su,
       pa_usrrf_stud rf
  WHERE su.col_num  = rf.col_num
  AND su.user_value = rf.user_id
  AND su.col_num    = 300
  AND su.stud_id    = sq.stud_id
  AND ROWNUM=1) AS region,
( SELECT rf.user_desc as region
  FROM pa_stud_user su,
       pa_usrrf_stud rf
  WHERE su.col_num  = rf.col_num
  AND su.user_value = rf.user_id
  AND su.col_num    = 400
  AND su.stud_id    = sq.stud_id
  AND ROWNUM=1) AS district
...
```

Just that simple.